# select entries from database where db timestamp is 10 minutes less than current timestamp

Tags: mysql, timestamp

I have a column named time_stamp in my table. I need to get the latest 2 entries that are entered 10 minutes before the current time.. 
example: if current time is 2013-09-06 09:47:37 , then I need to get the two rows entered 10 minutes before. please anybody help me with the query.. ??

I used this query but its not working:

`mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE time_stamp>=(NOW()-INTERVAL 10 MINUTES)");`

Comment: Can you try SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE time_stamp>=SUBTIME(NOW(),'00:10:00.0000') ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what exactly you mean by *...10 minutes before the current time...* it might be

```
SELECT * 
  FROM Table1
 WHERE time_stamp < NOW() - INTERVAL 10 MINUTE
 ORDER BY time_stamp DESC
 LIMIT 2
```

or (which is essentially what you've already tried)

```
SELECT * 
  FROM Table1
 WHERE time_stamp >= NOW() - INTERVAL 10 MINUTE
 ORDER BY time_stamp
 LIMIT 2
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/543a11/3)** demo

Answer (score 1):

I think this will do

```
SELECT * FROM table1  WHERE
timestamp  < DATE_SUB(NOW() , INTERVAL 10 MINUTE) 
ORDER BY timestamp desc
LIMIT 2
```